# Will brushless fan speed depend on amperage?

Tags: dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor

I am not a technical guy and have no knowledge in electrical subject.

I use brushless fans in my regular day to day activity. We use them for pellet stoves and hence my question:

Will amperage rating of brushless motor decide RPM of the motor ?

What is the best brushless motor to run continuous for 8 hours, both on battery and direct power, in stoves ?

Brushless fans rated for 220v and 1 amp motors are used up till now. They are not providing enough pressure for fire and getting useless within 100 hours of usage as these motors will attract heavy heat from stove body.

Please suggest the solution for the same.

Answer (score 3):

Fans used in this manner, where high heat is involved, are going to fail quickly unless design techniques keep the temperature of the motor and its bearings within the ratings specified by the fan manufacturer.

So you need to be sure to place fans on the upstream side of the combustion area so that they push the air into the stove as opposed to trying to suck air from the combustion area. Secondly the fans need to be mounted on some type of ducting that moves them far enough away from the combustion chamber that so that they can remain cool enough to survive for their expected normal lifetime.

I suspect that your current failures are bearing problems resulting in the motors seizing up and thus being unable to turn. You should research motor bearing types and find fans with bearings specifically designed for higher temperature operation.

Answer (score 1):

Michael Karas gives you some very good advice, but he doesn't answer the actual question:

> Will amperage rating of brushless motor decide RPM of the motor?

No, but the two values are related. The speed of the motor is implicit in its design. Obviously, if a fan motor is designed to spin faster, it requires more power, which means that it needs to draw more current at a given voltage.

However, if you have two fans, and one draws more current that the other, it may mean that it spins faster and moves more air, or it may mean that is just a less efficient design.

You really need to be looking at the CFM (Cubic Feet of air per Minute) ratings of the fans you're buying, since this is the parameter that directly relates to your application.